# is there any way to add image in rtf file programmatically in IOS?

Tags: ios, image, rtf

can you guys  please suggest me how to add image and text in rtf file programmetically  in iOS

Answer (score 0):

Here is a github project that does support the rtf in it. Although it is an old project it should be a good guide to know how to do it. I haven't tested it yet in iOS 6 but I'm sure it can be modified to be applicable. The author says it is a good replacement for uitextview so give it a shot and let me know if this works for you or not.

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView

here is a complete project that does the following:

- Bold, Italics and Underlining
- Highlighting (via UIMenuController)
- Font Size adjustment
- Font Color adjustment
- Font adjustment
- Undo and Redo
- Image insertion
- Draggable images
- Auto updating bar items which display the current state
- Bonus Code Hiding keyboard accessory view
- Bonus Code Hiding all other items in UIMenuController

hope this helps you out.

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-sample-project/

Comment: the sample code mentioned  does support text only, do you have any specific code which can support image insertion in rtf thorough objective C ?

Comment: check my edited answer please. hope this one helps you out.

Comment: Thanks Code Monkey for your help, however it doesn't fulfill my requirement.The code is nor able to generate a rtf file with embedded images  which can be shared like a pdf file. It only creates a web-view.

Comment: My main aim is to generate a rtf file with images embedded which can be shared through mail composer in native environment of iOS ? Please see if you can help